# Order of raw_inputs being asked is unexpected when creating a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I had a piece of code like this:

```
terms = {}
while 1:
    terms[raw_input('input latin: ')] = raw_input('input meaning: ')
```

I was expecting to first input a latin word, and then give its translation, which then would be added to a dictionary.

However, I was prompted with this:

```
$ python latinvocab.py
input meaning:
```

Notice how the translation is asked for first, instead of the latin.

---

Obviously a way to bypass this would be to introduce some variables and perhaps do:

```
terms = {}
while 1:
    latin = raw_input('input latin: ')
    translation = raw_input('input meaning: ')
    terms[latin] = translation
```

But what's happening with the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand side of an assignment statement is always evaluated before the left-hand side, as described (although not totally explicitly) [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).  This is natural because in an assignment like `x = someFunction()`, it has to evaluate `someFunction()` before it can assign its value to anything.